# sql linked server 2008 with sybase 15.5 limits rows to 100

Tags: sql-server-2008, sap-ase, linked-server

The following query always gives a resulset of 100 records (although there are many more).

```
select * from openquery (SybaseLinkedServer, 'SELECT F1, F2 FROM db.dbo.table where F1 in (120, 125, 126, 127) and F2 in (4,6,8)')
```

I tried to add TOP 10000 in both selects, with no result.

Linked server was setup in sql management studio 2012 on a 2008 database. ODBC driver for sybase-ase is 3.51 (sybase 15.5).

Does someone know a solution for this problem?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to set up the link server using `OLE DB` instead of `ODBC` driver.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue.
The root cause is that you've set up your linked server using `ODBC` instead of `OLE DB`.

Below link will help you to created db link to Sybase from Sql Server Mgnt Studio:

> http://sql-articles.com/articles/dba/creating-linked-server-to-sybase-from-sql-server/

Comment: Hi @Avijit, it seems that I used this procedure to create my connection. I've used the Microsoft OLE DB for ODBC Drivers option to connect to my ODBC datasource.

Comment: Have you tried using SQL Anywhere. Here is the link:  http://hodentekmsss.blogspot.in/2014/07/creating-linked-server-to-sapsybase-sql.html